# Perl - Gather all of STDIN until blank line or EOF

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, stdin

How can I gather all lines from STDIN lines until a blank line or EOF, whichever comes first. It would look something like:

```
 my @lines;

 while(<> ne EOF || <> not blank) {
      chomp;
      push(@lines, $_);
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To break on EOF or a blank line:

```
while ( ($_ = <>) =~ /\S/ ) {
   chomp;
   push @lines, $_;
}
```

`/\S/` tests whether the input contains any non-whitespace.

Comment: Actually, no. That will issue a warning if there are no blank lines.

Comment: ikegami: not if you don't have warnings enabled :)

Comment: I think that `while( defined($_ = <>) and /\S/ ){...}` would be better.

Comment: I think Ilmari Karonen's answer is better.

Answer (score 7):

To stop reading input on EOF or a blank line, I would prefer this solution:

```
while (<>) {
    last unless /\S/;
    # do something with $_ here...
}
```

Unlike mob's solution, this will not give a warning about "*Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)*" on EOF.

Answer (score 1):

If "blank" line means no characters inside, just new-line `\n` (Unix) or `\r\n` (Windows), then use

```
my @lines;
/^$/ && last, s/\r?\n$//, push(@lines, $_) while <>;
```

(see [this demo](http://ideone.com/rNhpPF))

---

If "blank" line should have any number of white-space inside, such as `"         "`, then use

```
my @lines;
/^\s*$/ && last, s/\r?\n$//, push(@lines, $_) while <>;
```

Comment: All your answers only break if CTRL+D is pressed

Comment: The <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is only required to signal EOF when working at the terminal. If the input is produced in any other way, e.g. files or pipes, the EOF is implicit, and the program terminates.

Comment: That is true amon.  I did not think about that.

Answer (score 0):

This will only check for EOF:

```
while (<>) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

So you need to add a check for blank lines:

```
while (<>) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    last if $_ eq "";
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

---

Alternatively,

```
while (<>) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

is short for

```
while (defined( $_ = <> )) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

so if you wanted the whole condition in the `while` condition, you'd use

```
while (defined( $_ = <> ) && /\S/) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

Comment: Unlike the answer you accepted, neither of these solutions warn.

Comment: Unlike Ωmega's solution, neither of these solutions make the unusual assumption that trailing whitespace is significant.

Comment: @Ωmega, Thanks for stating the obvious and showing the deficiencies of `chomp` for me.